# How to restore/fix windows 10 taskbar icon size

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I woke up today to find only particular icons pinned on my taskbar now being displayed incorrectly. Within the screenshot you can see the mail and calendar icons displaying incorrectly, while the others are fine.

[image: mail and calendar icons shrank]

I saw no system updates come in overnight. I've rebooted. I've removed the items from the bar and re-opened/re-added. Has anyone else experienced this and found a fix?

Comment: Did you change the accent color to orange?

Comment: @Biswa yes, it has been for many months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all my initial attempts didn't work, I ended up going into settings->apps and went to advanced for Mail and Calendar. I reset the app entirely, rebooted, and my icons were back to normal. Must have just been a goofy windows issue...

Info found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_cal/mail-and-calendar-app-icons-shrunk/8a4b2204-7560-45d2-b3f9-2293e0210143)